# Are there nontrivial equations for hyperoperations above exponentiation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra, big-numbers, hyperoperation

A similar question was asked in [comments elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078937/what-nice-properties-does-exponentiation-have/2080920).

A paper by Roberto Di Cosmo and Thomas Dufour (["The Equational Theory of 〈ℕ, 0, 1, + , ×, ↑〉 Is Decidable, but Not Finitely Axiomatisable"](http://www.dicosmo.org/Articles/zeroisnfa.pdf)) asserts in footnote 2 (p.3) that it has been shown **"that there are no nontrivial equations for $⟨\mathbb{N}, \mathrm{Ack}(n, \_, \_)⟩$ if $n > 2.$"** References make it clear that $\mathrm{Ack}(n,x,y)=H_{n+1}(x,y)$ in the [hyperoperation sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Definition), so the assertion is as follows:

> $\text{There are no nontrivial equations for the binary function }(\_\uparrow^y\_)\text{ if }y>1\\ \text{ (i.e., for hyperoperations above exponentiation)}\tag{*}.$

(For this, the above paper cites Charles F. Martin, "Axiomatic bases for equational theories of natural numbers", Notices
of the Am. Math. Soc., 19(7):778, 1972, which I have not found online.)

**Q.1**: What, precisely, is meant by a "nontrivial equation" here?

(The defining recursion $$x\uparrow^{y+1}(z+1)=x\uparrow^y (x\uparrow^{y+1}z),$$ which certainly holds for $y>1$, is evidently considered trivial.)

**Q.2**: Is the following a valid proof based on assertion $(*)$? ...

**Claim**:

If $x,y,z$ are integers $\gt 1$, then the value of $\ x\uparrow^y z\ $ uniquely determines $x,y,z$; i.e., 
$$x\uparrow^y z = x'\uparrow^{y'} z' \quad\implies\quad x=x',\ y=y',\ z=z'.\quad \tag{1}$$

(The purpose of restricting the domain to integers $>1$ is to remove obvious counterexamples that arise from equations like $x\uparrow (a\cdot z) = (x\uparrow a)\uparrow z\ \ $ or $\ \ 2\uparrow^y 2=4\uparrow^{y'} 1\ \ $ or $\ \ 1\uparrow^y z=1\uparrow^{y'} z'.$)

**Proof**:

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there is a counterexample to $(1)$, in which the LHS of the implication holds but not the RHS. Then the LHS is a nontrivial equation for some hyperoperation(s) beyond exponentiation, which is impossible as per $(*)$. QED

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the linked question and its answer, it's important to realize that the word "equation" has a very precise meaning in this context.

*Quick summary of what follows: the defining recursion of the Ackermann function is nontrivial, but isn't an equation in the right language; and the argument in question 2 is incorrect, since equations involve quantifying over all elements of the structure.*

First off, we need to define *terms*. A term in a functional language *(which is just a collection of function symbols, nothing too complicated; the word "functional" is included because we often consider other kinds of languages)* is an expression built from the function symbols in that language, variables, and parentheses; an *equation* is then a sentence of the form $$\forall x_1,...,x_n(s(x_1, ..., x_n)=t(x_1, ..., x_n)),$$ where $s, t$ are terms in the variables $x_1, ..., x_n$. For instance, the language of groups contains a binary function symbol (the group operation), a unary function symbol (the inverse operation), and a nullary function symbol (the identity element).

By contrast, the definition by recursion of the Ackermann function isn't an equation in the relevant language: that language consists **only** of the binary function symbol "$\uparrow^n$," and the defining recursion involves the symbol "$+$" as well. So the definition of "equation" is quite strict. Note that this crops up in a few places in the linked question, where several properties of exponentiation are proposed which are not, in fact, equations in the language of exponentiation alone.

A *structure* in a given functional language is just a set, together with some functions corresponding to the function symbols (with the correct arities). For instance, if our language $\Sigma$ consists of two unary function symbols $@$ and $\%$, then one example of a $\Sigma$-structure is $(\mathbb{Z}; @(x)=x+1, \%(x)=x-1)$. It should be clear what it means for an equation to hold in a structure - for instance, in the above structure the equation $$\forall x(@(\%(x))=\%(@(x))).$$ holds.

An equation is *trivial* if it is true no matter how the function symbols are interpreted. That is, given a functional language $\Sigma$, an equation $E$ in the language $\Sigma$ is trivial if it is true in every $\Sigma$-structure. For instance, the equation from the previous paragraph *isn't* trivial: consider the $\Sigma$-structure where both $@(x)$ and $\%(x)$ are interpreted as "$x+1$."

It's not hard to convince yourself that there really aren't very many of these; in fact, an equation is trivial iff the two terms are exactly the same! So that further justifies the name.

This answers your first question. Towards the second, note the **universal quantifier** in the definition of an equation: simply having an instance of one thing equalling another doesn't constitute an equation, an equation specifies that two specific terms are **always** equal. So the answer to your second question is no.

---

Incidentally, the most relevant subject here is [**universal algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer!